# PHP call_user_func_array() error

Tags: php

I am getting this error can not find this php file anywhere.

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'ms_whitespace_fix' not found or invalid function name in /home/djglive/public_html/asaabforever.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

/* white space below menu fix */
```

/*function ms_whitespace_fix() {

```
if( ( is_category() == true ) || ( is_product_category() == true ) || ( is_single() == true ) ) { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .has-fixed-menu:not(.has-transparent-menu) .page-wrapper {
            padding-top: 0 !important;
        }
        @media all and ( max-width: 1150px ) {
            .has-fixed-menu:not(.has-transparent-menu) .page-wrapper {
                margin-top: -6px;
            }
        }
    </style>
<?php }
```

}*/

Comment: `ms_whitespace_fix` is being called from a `add_hook` or `add_filter` somewhere, but that function does not exist. You need to see if you can find that text in a theme or plugin, and if you cant find it then you can try to use the default theme and see if that error still appears. Also, you can disable all plugins and then try to enable one by one until the error appears again.

Comment: the `ms_` prefix should give you a clue as to what plugin or theme is adding this hook, eg. Multiple Styles or Mega Stack etc.

Comment: It seems to be related to the theme (907 Theme) it did not go away when plugins were deactivated. But disappeared when I switched over to the 1917 theme.

Comment: found this in my function.php

/* white space below menu fix */

/*function ms_whitespace_fix() {

 if( ( is_category() == true ) || ( is_product_category() == true ) || ( is_single() == true ) ) { ?>
  <style type="text/css">
   .has-fixed-menu:not(.has-transparent-menu) .page-wrapper {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
   }
   @media all and ( max-width: 1150px ) {
    .has-fixed-menu:not(.has-transparent-menu) .page-wrapper {
     margin-top: -6px;
    }
   }
  </style>
 <?php }

}*/

Comment: I saw there error in the code. I edited it and seems to be resolved.